# Finding A Spanning Set

Tags: vector-spaces

How do I find the spanning set for:

$$V = \{(2a,b,0)\ :\ a,b \in \mathbb{R} \},$$

where $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You first set, say $a=1,b=0$, then $a=0, b=1$.

Comment: Why would you set a=1 and b=0?

Comment: Because the vectors $(1,0)$  and $(0,1)$  are a basis of $\mathbf R^2$, and  $(2a,b,0)$ can be written as $\;a(2,0,0)+b(0,1,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
(2a,b,0) = a(2,0,0) + b(0,1,0)
$$
for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
it follows that the set $\{ (2,0,0), (0,1,0) \}$ is a spanning set for $V$.